# How to define this complex labor rule as a constraint in MIP?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming

Im trying to define a complex labor rule as constraints in a MIP, solved with CPLEX.
My key decision variable is a binary x(i,j) indicating if shift i is assigned to employee j.
The labor rule is as follows (standard Dutch labor law):

- in every period of 7*24 hours (at every start of a shift a new 'period' starts, so not 7 full days!), an employee must have an uninterrupted rest of at least 36 hours between two shifts OR
- in every period of 14*24 hours (same definition of period), the employee has sufficient uninterrupted rests of at least 32hours, adding up to at least 72 hours.

A rest must be fully within the period.
So if the initial shift (hence the period) starts at Dec 1 08:00, and there are shifts on each day with the last one ending on Dec 6 22:00, the first part of the rule is violated, since the rest is only 34 hours from Dec 6 22:00 until Dec 8 08:00.

What I have thought of so far:

- I can define a continuous variable as the rest after a shift, and sum those (smartly), but given that last example, I would need a max(rest, endofperiod) making it nonlinear. In other words: the usable rest after a shift depends on the start of the period
- I can 'simplify' the rule by making 3 (or more...) binary variables: Is32, Is36, Is40 hours of rest. Then I'd either have the 36 in the first week, or a valid combination of the others in 2 weeks. We know which variables to include in the sum, because we can check beforehand if the 32/36/40 hours are completely within the period. This is however an imperfect solution, as it would not allow (for example) two rests of 34 and 38 hours (as the would be marked as 32 and 36, hence not adding up to 72)

Do you have any (well performing) suggestions?
Thank you in advance!
PS: this is my first post here, I hope I made everything clear...

Comment: The first rule is usually easily decomposable into implications like `(x_i -> (!x_i+1 && !x_i+2 && ..)` which naturally form cliques and those are heavily exploited in MILP solvers. The other rule is much more complex as those have some freedom. I for myself love [DFA-based approaches](https://sofdem.github.io/art/demassey14cmp.pdf) which are basically network-flow models within your MILP (can be made hard- or soft-constraints).There surely is some initial learning-curve AND if that's a good idea depends a bit on your time-discretization granularity / horizon-width and DFA-size (rule-"states")

Comment: Please move this from Stack Overflow to Operations Research as there isn't any code.

Comment: Sascha, thank you for your reply. If I'm not mistaking, your constraint 'only' checks IF a shift has 32h of rest after it. However, this is not required for every shift, only for every period. So we need at least 2 constraints: one checking IF there is such a rest after each shift. The other checking there is at least one such shift with rest in every period.